# How to obtain a MKPlacemark Address for a callout c# xamarin

Tags: ios, dictionary, xamarin, mkannotationview, renderer

I'm trying to get the addresses. All I have so far in getting the coordinates using

```
 CLLocation loc = new CLLocation(anno.Coordinate.Latitude, anno.Coordinate.Longitude);
```

However, I tried the reverse geocode and placemark. None of them works. 
The following example is not finish and it is not proper formatted. I'm just copying from swift.

```
 async void ReverseGeocodeToConsoleAsync(CLLocation location)
                {
                    var geoCoder = new CLGeocoder();
                    var placemarks = await 
                    geoCoder.ReverseGeocodeLocationAsync(location);
                    var placemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark;
                    var addressString = "";
                    //String to hold address
                        var locatedAtcountry = placemark.country;
                        var locatedAtcity = placemark.locality;
                        var locatedAtisocountry = placemark.ISOcountryCode;
                if (placemark.ISOcountryCode == "TW") /*Address Format in Chinese*/
                {
                    if (placemark.country != null)
                    {
                        addressString = placemark.country!
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is close to success. Here's a sample which can get the address from the location.

```
        public void GetAddress(CLLocation loc)
        {
            CLGeocoder ceo = new CLGeocoder();

            ceo.ReverseGeocodeLocation(loc, (placemarks, error) =>
            {
                CLPlacemark placemark = placemarks[0];
                if (placemark != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(placemark.IsoCountryCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(placemark.Country);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much !  after all this trying with the map class renderer . I decided to move to a page renderer better . The UiSearchBar is not working because I dont know how to set the event for it .Ideally, I would like to do something similar to this .but using the search bar .

Comment: async void Handle_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchBar.Text))
            {
                var address = SearchBar.Text;
                var approximateLocations = await Geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(address);//no completed

Comment: You may trigger it like : `searchbar.SearchButtonPressed += (sender, e) => { /*Work to be done at time of Search button click*/ };`